# My textarea creates "\n" "\r" characters every time page is submitted

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
MIKE
MIKE
```

turns to:

```
MIKE\r\nMIKE
```

I have tried

```
preg_replace('~\r?\n~','<br/>', $string);
```

This does not work.
Did I write it wrong? or is there another way to just replace the \r\n chars to blank space?

Comment: You've got a line break in your textarea, so yes, it will be submitted with line breaks. `\r\n` is a Windows-style break.

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? If you remove them, on retrieving they will be in one line

Comment: hmm thats true, what is the best way to maintain the space without displaying the \r\n's

Comment: If you save them in DB, let it be saved as is; on retrieving use `nl2br($the_value);` but if you want to show it again in textarea you even won't need it

Comment: I tried using your function. I save it to a DB and then re display it, but it just displays as MIKE\r\nMIKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is literally searching for carriage returns and new lines (`\n\r`).

you probably wanted to search for them in their string form.

```
preg_replace('~\\r\\n~','<br/>', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use str_replace I think. No need to use regular expressions

Comment: Question is asked for a specific case. It wants to remove those characters and this can do it so it is an answer I think.